# Split individual json to separate list

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have the following nested json list.
I have loopJson implemented, however it is not recursive and it does not pass the first object list. It would be great if someone could suggest the place that the recursive call should be made so it will perform recursion.

```
{
"key": "math",
"right": {
    "key": "Math"
},
"left": {
    "key": "A Greek–English Lexicon",
    "right": {
        "key": "A-list"
    },
    "left": {
        "key": "ASCII"
    }
}
}

      var loopJson = function(json){

      if(json.left.key != null){
          that.arrayTest.push({key:json.key,left:json.left.key});
      }
      if(json.right.key != null){
          that.arrayTest.push({key:json.key,right:json.right.key});
      }
  }
```

**The goal:**
Iterate through each object and create an array of objects consist of object with the keys("key","right") or ("key","left"). As the current json is nested, I would like to split the json into an array of objects. However, it is not iterating through each object as it is not recursive. I had to find a way to make it recursive.

An example of expected output :

```
[{key:"math",right:"Math"},{key:"math",left: "A Greek–English Lexicon"},{key: "A Greek–English Lexicon",left:""ASCII},{key: "A Greek–English Lexicon",right:"A-list"}]
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the function? or better what do you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = {
    "key": "math",
    "right": {
        "key": "Math"
    },
    "left": {
        "key": "A Greek–English Lexicon",
        "right": {
            "key": "A-list"
        },
        "left": {
            "key": "ASCII"
        }
    }
};

var nestedMethod = function(input) {
  var output = [];
  
  if (input.right) {
    output.push({ key: input.key, right: input.right.key });
    output = output.concat(nestedMethod(input.right));
  }
    
  if (input.left) {
    output.push({ key: input.key, left: input.left.key });
    output = output.concat(nestedMethod(input.left));
  }
  
  return output;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(nestedMethod(input)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with a recursive function and a fixed array of properties, to look after.

```js
var object = {
        "key": "math",
        "right": {
            "key": "Math"
        },
        "left": {
            "key": "A Greek–English Lexicon",
            "right": {
                "key": "A-list"
            },
            "left": {
                "key": "ASCII"
            }
        }
    },
    array = [];

function getParts(object, array) {
    ['right', 'left'].forEach(function (k) {
        var o;
        if (object[k]) {
            o = { key: object.key };
            o[k] = object[k].key;
            array.push(o);
            getParts(object[k], array);
        }
    });
}

getParts(object, array);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```